# Smooth Zoom and Pan all items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a vertical LinearLayout. The content consists of a list of images. Users should have the ability to zoom and pan, affecting all the images simultaneously. When a user zooms in, making the image larger, it eventually requires a change in the size of its container. Currently, I don't modify the container during the pinch gesture; instead, when the gesture ends, we fetch a new version of the image with zoom and horizontal pan capabilities, and we handle vertical scrolling. Not surprisingly, there's a UI glitch. After the user performs the gesture, we see the image as it should be (though it's cut off since its container hasn't expanded), then we update it with the new image and scroll, eventually achieving the desired result. However, the image update and scroll aren't synchronized in any way. Thus, you see the original content, some scrolling, and then the new image back in the right place.

Is there a way to group these updates so that, for instance, I could scroll, change the container's size, and update the matrix on the imageView, ensuring that all three changes are seen simultaneously? I should certainly be able to synchronize the container size change and matrix update (perform both changes before calling invalidate), but synchronizing the scroll seems tricky.

As I was writing this, I became convinced that I could update the container's size, scroll, and update the matrix as the user was performing the gesture. However, if I don't call suppressLayout(true), the gesture doesn't work very well, and with suppressLayout(true), I can't make changes to the RecyclerView (although I can still make changes to the individual items, but not scroll or resize the items).

I really want the user to perceive the entire list of images as one long image, allowing seamless zooming and panning. I feel like the RecyclerView is working against me. Is the solution to superimpose an invisible imageView over the RecyclerView, perform zooming and panning there, update the RecyclerView once the gesture is done, and wait for it to settle before making the imageView invisible again?  Other suggestions?

Comment: I know there's joke that if you explain an issue to smart friend, you usually figure it out by the time you're done explaining it (and a dog that tilts it head would do).  After posting this, I'm working on putting in overlay to handle scale and pan, it's not done, it's far enough along that feel like it's going to work out well.

Answer (score 0):

I got zoom and pan working by creating ImageView overlay (actually a customized ImageView), which is exactly the same size as the recyclerView.  I precalculated the image for ImageView by concatenating the images that are currently visible. Cutting them down (and sometimes adding a spacer), so I have an image that exactly represents what currently visible in the recyclerView.

I went through a couple of difference rounds for figuring when to calculate the image for the overlay.  In the end what worked well, was deriving a custom  LinearLayoutManager and overriding onLayoutComplete:

```
    override fun onLayoutCompleted(state: RecyclerView.State?) {
    super.onLayoutCompleted(state)
    onLayoutCompleted()
}
```

where onLayoutCompleted() is lambda passed to the constructor of the custom LinearLayoutManager.   onLayoutCompleted gets called more often than we need, so I keep track of the range of rows, the zoom, the pan, and offset to the top of the first visible row.   If none of them have changed, then there's no need to recalculate the composite image for the overlay.

When we see a two finger touch, we make the overlay visible if not already visible.  When the touch gesture ends, we call a lambda from the custom ImageView implemented by the Fragment that holds both the imageView and the recyclerView.  This is where things get a little tricky (and ugly).   From the matrix on imageView, we update the zoom, pan, and figure out how far we need to scroll.

We notify the recyclerView items that they have changed (they all have changed once the zoom and pan has changed, but note you really want to                     notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount), not notifyDataSetChanged()
).  Here comes the ugly part.   It's easy enough to figure how far to scroll, but for the scroll to be reliable, it needs to be done after the recyclerView has relaid everything out.

```
                vb.recyclerView.doOnNextLayout {
                Timber.d("onImageTouchEnded: doOnNextLayout")
                handler.postDelayed({
                    // This is a little ugly, but we need to wait for the layout to finish
                    // doOnNextLayout doesn't seem to be enough
                    vb.recyclerView.scrollBy(0, -scroll.roundToInt())
                    hideZoomOverlayOnNextScrollIdle = true
                    handler.postDelayed({
                        // We hope this is handling by the onScrollListener, this is a fallback
                        Timber.d("onImageTouchEnded: doOnNextLayout: hideZoomOverlayOnNextScrollIdle: $hideZoomOverlayOnNextScrollIdle")
                        if (hideZoomOverlayOnNextScrollIdle || vb.scaleOverlay.isVisible) {
                            hideZoomOverlayOnNextScrollIdle = false
                            vb.scaleOverlay.gone()
                            suspendSetupZoomOverlay = false
                        }
                    }, HIDE_OVERLAY_DELAY_MS)
                }, SCROLL_DELAY_MS)
            }
        }
```

I was hoping doOnNextLayout would tell where the layout was done, but there's often several items, we appear to get doOnNextLayout called after the first one is laid, so we add a delay.   We set a flag to tell the onScroll handler to hide the overlay on the next idle, but its not reliable, so after a delay, we hide the overlay if still visible.

This is all working well.  There are 4 things I'd like to fix:

1. Figure when to do the scroll and hide the overlay without arbitrary delays.
2. Sometimes there small jumps between the recyclerView and overlay (though most of time its dead on).
3. Since the image in the overlay is exactly the same size as the recyclerView when zooming out the image is cut off.  This is fixable.  I made it exactly the same size as the recyclerView, but it could larger, and scaled down, it just needs to keep the same aspect ratio.
4. <s>There's a little too much overhead. We are updating a decorator at a fairly high rate (a few times a second).  The decorator updates cause a onLayoutCompleted call, which adds enough overhead that some of the decorator updates are missed. I suspect this is fixable.  May have to disable the onLayoutCompleted at times (which will mean so more logic to make sure we update the composite image if the anything moves).</s>

Comment: I was seeing an issue with decorators not updating fast enough.  The issue was completely unrelated.